# Python import a module into one class only

Tags: python, import

I am trying to get a module to import, but only if an object of a specific class is called.  For example:

```
class One(object):
    try:
        import OneHelper
    except ImportError:
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        # this function doesn't use OneHelper
        ...

    def blah(self):
        # this function does
        OneHelper.blah()
```

This causes a `NameError: global name 'OneHelper' is not defined` when the `One.blah()` function is called. So far the only thing I have found that works is importing the module into the actual functions that use it. So:

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # this function doesn't use OneHelper
        ...

    def blah(self):
        try:
            import OneHelper
        except ImportError:
            pass
        # this function does
        OneHelper.blah()
```

But I don't want to have to import the module in each function I want to use it in, I want it to be available to the whole class, but *only* if an instance of that class is instantiated.  Apologies if I'm not being clear enough...

Comment: You could try creating a function that imports the class if instantiated and then just calling the function from within the other functions. Small workaround maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `import OneHelper` works fine in the class, making it a class attribute. You can verify this with `dir(One)` after defining your class -- there's your `OneHelper` attribute.  `One.OneHelper` is a reference to the module. In an instance, of course, you may access it as `self.OneHelper` from your methods. (You could also continue to access it as `One.OneHelper`.)

Comment: Don't feel stupid... it is perfectly reasonable to assume that `import` always imports to the module's global namespace because that's what happens in 99.44% of uses. Of course, that's not actually how it works, but it's not an unreasonable starting point. I had to test it out myself to be sure how it behaves. Fortunately, when you're not sure, a little experimentation and inspection will get you a long way in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Import it on `__init__` and attribute to some property:

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            import OneHelper
        except ImportError:
            self.OneHelper = None
        else:
            self.OneHelper = OneHelper
    def blah(self):
        if self.OneHelper:
            self.OneHelper.blah()
```

Your example looks funny because if the module fails to import what is the point of calling it later?

Comment: +1 you should almost never catch an exception and do nothing in the `except` block, and that goes double for `ImportError`, which you should almost never catch at all (i.e. only when you have a fallback of some sort).

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using `global  OneHelper` before importing the module. This adds the OneHelper to the global namespace.